# kotlin object conversion in lambdas convert

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to have this compiling:

```
val criteriaList = aList.stream().map { dateRange -> {
            Criteria.where("KEY").`is`(dateRange) } }.toList().toTypedArray()

Criteria().orOperator(*criteriaList)
```

But:

```
Criteria().orOperator(*criteriaList)
```

Currently does not compile:

> ```
> Type mismatch.
> Required:
> Array<(out) Criteria!>!
> Found:
> Array<(() → Criteria!)!>
> ```

Why?

Comment: why are you using stream api?

Answer (score 2):

You are mapping your `dateRange` to a `() -> Criteria`.
You do not need to wrap what is following after `->` with curly braces. Check also the [Kotlin reference regarding Lambda expression syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax):

> `val sum = { x: Int, y: Int -> x + y }`
>
> A lambda expression is always surrounded by curly braces [...], the body goes after an `->` sign. If the inferred return type of the lambda is not
> `Unit`, the last (or possibly single) expression inside the lambda body is treated as the return value.

So you could just write the following instead:

```
.map { dateRange -> Criteria.where("KEY").`is`(dateRange) }
```

Note also that you do not really need to call `stream()`, but you can directly call `map` on it (except it wouldn't be a real `List` in the first place).

So your code could probably be simplified to something like:

```
val criteriaList = aList.map { dateRange -> Criteria.where("KEY").`is`(dateRange) }
                        .toTypedArray()
```

or

```
val criteriaList = aList.map { Criteria.where("KEY").`is`(it) }
                        .toTypedArray()
```